# Cannot read property *0* of null

Tags: javascript

I get this error "Cannot read property '0' of null."

I have a table with

somename.html

```
<table>  
    <tr>  
    <td id="td1">text</td>  
    </tr>  
    </table>
```

somename.js

```
function test(){  
    var date=new Date();  
    if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() >=13  && date.getMinutes() >=3 ){ //8-9AM  
        document.getElementById('td1')[0].style.color = 'blue';  
    }else if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() == 14  && date.getMinutes() <= 20){  
            document.getElementById('td1')[0].style.color = 'blue';  
    }else{  
      //nothing  
    }  
}  
setInterval(test(),1000);
```

EDIT: new error if i remove [0] "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: `java.js` makes me cringe just like `php.py` :)

Comment: issue is with `document.getElementById('td1')[0]` I guess

Comment: Use `setInterval(test,1000);`

Comment: @Satpal Post that as an answer, but also include everyone else's fix to the array index.

Comment: Any chance that you have this JS code in the `<head>` section instead of in the `<body>` section?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getElementById` returns `null` if there is no match in the document. (Which then leads to exactly your error message).

This means that either you have a typo in your selector or the html or the js gets executed before your element is included into the dom.

Also, `getElementById` returns a single element and not an array (`Node List` to be precise), so the correct call would be:

```
document.getElementById('td1').style.color = 'blue';
```

Third problem:

```
setInterval(test(),1000);
//              /\
// this will immeditately execute the function and
// hands over the *return value* to setInterval
```

will not work as intended, it needs to be

```
setInterval(test,1000);
//            /\
// hand over the *function reference* to be executed after 1 second
```

Comment: so if i link my script in the <head></head> it will not execute something that is posted in <body></body>?

Comment: fixed it il add as answer in 5 min thanks :D did not know i hadde to post a link to a script at the bottom of my <body></body>

Comment: @KevinHaugen - Correct. Browsers can actually run JavaScript even if the page hasn't finished loading. I suggest you read about event handlers to learn how to make your code wait.

Comment: yes I am still juggling on learning php, java and css
any websites other then w3school to help me learn?

Comment: @Kevin For your own good, you should avoid w3schools, read [here why](http://www.w3fools.com/) - there are also some very good alternative resources listed.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('td1')` returns you the element, and not an array. Remove the `[0]`.

You could also perform a check on whether the element exists before trying to use it:

```
function test() {  
    var elem = document.getElementById('td1');
    if(typeof elem == 'undefined') return;

    var date = new Date();
    if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() >=13  && date.getMinutes() >=3 ) { //8-9AM  
        elem.style.color = 'blue';  
    } else if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() == 14  && date.getMinutes() <= 20) {  
        elem.style.color = 'blue';  
    } else {  
      //nothing  
    }  
}  
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Comment: But the error message says it's null, not an element.

Comment: @KevinHaugen See Satpal's comment.

Answer (score 0):

if your `id` is unique then this will work

```
document.getElementById('td1').style.color = 'blue';
```

Comment: This will probably just change the error to `Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setInterval`, you must supply a function. You're calling the function immediately, not passing the function to `setInterval`. It should be:

```
setInterval(test, 1000);
```

Since you're calling it immediately, it's running before the DOM has loaded fully, and the `td1` element isn't found. So `getElementById` returns `null` instead of the element.

In addition, as the other answers pointed out, you should not use `[0]` to access the element returned by `getElementById`. It returns a single element, not a `NodeList`.