# JavascriptExecutor: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selenium-webdriver

I am using Javascript executor to remove `readonly` attribute but it is giving an error.
`Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null`.

I have seen different posts where people confirm that after removing AdBlock from Chrome it worked. I don't know what is AdBlock and how to remove it from Chrome Binary at runtime, so I tried Firefox (Gecko Driver) but it is also throwing the same error.

**Code:**

```
driver.get("http://jsfiddle.net/343Rb/");
runJS().executeScript("document.getElementById('myInput').removeAttribute('readonly')");
```

Browsers I tried:
Chrome Binary latest, Firefox (GeckoDriver latest) on Windows 7

Links I went through:

1. [TypeError: Cannot read property "removeAttribute" of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688197/typeerror-cannot-read-property-removeattribute-of-null)
2. [Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null: Cant find source of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143879/cannot-read-property-removeattribute-of-null-cant-find-source-of-it)
3. [Cannot read property *0* of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527922/cannot-read-property-0-of-null)

Few posts above are purely JS based so I believe is the reason they are not replying to me.

I am using Selenium 3.0, Windows 7, Firefox, Chrome, Java, Testng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element you want is inside an `<iframe>`. You need to switch to it before querying for your element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame('result');
```

Or:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name('result')));
```

Comment: You are right, I dont know why I didnt think of it.